# How to generate a normally distributed variable in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of 10 values:

```
variable=[2.1, 5.3, 4.1, 6.7, 2, 6.6, 1.9, 4.51, 4, 7.15]
```

Its length:

```
>>> len(variable)
10
```

Its average:

```
>>> mean(variable)
4.436
```

Its standard deviation:

```
>>> np.std(variable)
1.8987269419271429
```

From it I want to generate a `new_variable` having `len(new_variable)==100` and normally distributed where `mean==4.436` and `np.std==1.898`.

Comment: Check for numpy.random.randn or scipy.stats if you want fine grained control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function achieves exactly what you asked for by transforming a randomly generated distribution.

```
from statistics import NormalDist, mean, stdev

def get_target_dist(target_mean, target_std, size):
    dist = NormalDist(target_mean, target_std).samples(size)
    dist_mean, dist_std = mean(dist), stdev(dist)
    dist_standard = [(val - dist_mean) / dist_std for val in dist]
    dist_scaled = [val * target_std + target_mean for val in dist_standard]
    return dist_scaled

dist = get_target_dist(4.436, 1.898, 100)

print("len:", len(dist))
print("mean:", mean(dist))
print("std:", stdev(dist))

# len: 100
# mean: 4.436
# std: 1.898
```

Comment: Thanks and welcome to SO, does  `get_target_dist` work when `size` larger ?

Comment: Hi @KhaledDELLAL thank you! Sure, just execute e.g. "dist = get_dist(4.436, 1.898, 1000)" and check the result ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [random.gauss](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.gauss) function:

1 sample:

```
import random
x = random.gauss(4.436, 1.898)
```

or 100 samples:

```
import random
x = [random.gauss(4.436, 1.898) for _ in range(100)]
```

This is standard library, you don't need to install anything. You may also be interested in the [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) library.

Comment: Thanks, is `random.gauss`  the best method when the range becomes too larger ?

Comment: It should, as long as you stay within the bounds of floating point numbers